# C# to VB.net conversion About the Selenium waits Example

Tags: c#, vb.net, selenium, lambda, selenium-chromedriver

I can't figure out how to convert this code in the example text. How should I write it?

```
wait.Until(e => e.FindElement(By.XPath("//a/h3")));
```

Original Site : [Wait | Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/)

Original Code :

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Url = "https://www.google.com/ncr";
driver.FindElement(By.Name("q")).SendKeys("cheese" + Keys.Enter);
 
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement firstResult = wait.Until(e => e.FindElement(By.XPath("//a/h3")));

Console.WriteLine(firstResult.Text);
```

Ps. I would like to know the following as well

```
var foo = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
                    .Until(drv => drv.FindElement(By.Name("q")));
```

.Until:
■ Function DfaultWait(Of IwebDriver).Until(Of TResult)(condition As Func(Of IWebDriver, TResult))As TResult  (+ 1 overload)

Thank in Advance

ーーーーーーーーーーー

▼ I am glad to inform you that the problem is now solved.

```
Dim firstResult As IWebElement = Wait.Untile(Function(e) e.findElement(By.XPath("//a/h3")))
```

Thanks for replying.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting C# Lambda expression to VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41624432/converting-c-sharp-lambda-expression-to-vb-net)

Comment: Even a cursory search in the vb.net tag for "C# lambda" will provide myriad existing examples for how to translate the C# syntax to the VB syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
wait.Until(e => e.FindElement(By.XPath("//a/h3")));
```

is this

```
wait.Until(Function(e) e.FindElement(By.XPath("//a/h3")))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I'm getting a Error red underline BC36645 [I can't guess from these arguments.].
What should I do?

Comment: Set the data type of e to the expected data type of the lambda sub, like: `Sub(e As <expected data type>) e.FindElement.... End Sub`

Comment: I tried writhig <br/>
'wait.Until(sub(e As IWebElement) e.findElemen ...  End sub ) '<br/>
as instructed, but the error remained the sama.

Comment: Which line specifically is generating the error?

Comment: A red line of error is drawn for [ until ].

Comment: @catwalk, why do you think that providing an error code but no error message is a good idea? Do you think that we should all look up that error code for ourselves, even though you have the error message in front of you?

Comment: I don't know for sure but, given the context, I would assume that `Until` would require a value lambda rather than an action lambda, i.e. a `Function` rather than a `Sub`: `wait.Until(Function(e) e.FindElement(By.XPath("//a/h3")))`. Actually, the question makes that clear, i.e. the parameter is a `Func` rather than an `Action`.

Comment: I didn't write the error code because it was the same as the one in the top of the comment. The error code is BC36645.

Comment: Thank you, user17922293.
The error disappeared.

Comment: @catwalk, you DID provide the error code. What you didn't provide was the error message. You didn't provide either in the original question so how are we to know that it's the same now? We only know what you tell us so you have to provide ALL the relevant information. That's the point. We should have to guess, assume, infer or look up things that you already know. It should be obvious that an error message is provided as a diagnostic aid so, if you want us to help you diagnose the issue, you need to provide it to us.

Comment: Sorry, I'll be careful next time.

In the comment above, I wrote this, but should I include the error message in every comment?
[Thanks for the reply. I'm getting an Error red underline BC36645 [I can't guess from these arguments.] What should I do? ]